# install imageMagic 1and1

Tags: php, terminal, package

I'm trying to install ImageMagic on my server (mutualized) @ 1and1
I follow [this tutorial](http://faq.1and1.co.uk/web_space__access/ssh/7.html) but I allready have this :

```
  CC       filters/magick_libMagickCore_6_Q16_la-analyze.lo
  CCLD     magick/libMagickCore-6.Q16.la
copying selected object files to avoid basename conflicts...
  CC       wand/wand_libMagickWand_6_Q16_la-animate.lo
  CC       wand/wand_libMagickWand_6_Q16_la-compare.lo
  CC       wand/wand_libMagickWand_6_Q16_la-composite.lo
  CC       wand/wand_libMagickWand_6_Q16_la-conjure.lo
  CC       wand/wand_libMagickWand_6_Q16_la-convert.lo
virtual memory exhausted: Cannot allocate memory
make[2]: *** [wand/wand_libMagickWand_6_Q16_la-convert.lo] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory `/homepages/20/d300979466/htdocs/ImageMagick-6.8.6-7'
make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/homepages/20/d300979466/htdocs/ImageMagick-6.8.6-7'
make: *** [all] Error 2
(uiserver):u55223546:/homepages/20/d300979466/htdocs/ImageMagick-6.8.6-7 > make install 
make  install-recursive
make[1]: Entering directory `/homepages/20/d300979466/htdocs/ImageMagick-6.8.6-7'
Making install in .
make[2]: Entering directory `/homepages/20/d300979466/htdocs/ImageMagick-6.8.6-7'
  CC       wand/wand_libMagickWand_6_Q16_la-convert.lo
virtual memory exhausted: Cannot allocate memory
make[2]: *** [wand/wand_libMagickWand_6_Q16_la-convert.lo] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory `/homepages/20/d300979466/htdocs/ImageMagick-6.8.6-7'
make[1]: *** [install-recursive] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/homepages/20/d300979466/htdocs/ImageMagick-6.8.6-7'
make: *** [install] Error 2
(uiserver):u55223546:/homepages/20/d300979466/htdocs/ImageMagick-6.8.6-7 >
```

I follow the tutorial so where is the problem ?

Thx

Comment: It looks like 1&1 is not giving you enough memory on the shared host. If you are following their tutorial you can contact them and ask them for more memory. I have tried on my account and it gives me the exact same error on the same place.

Comment: Ok, so go to the phone...